# Clarify the hypotheses in the Banach-Alaoglu theorem

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis

In my functional analysis class, I was given the following theorem

**Banach-Alaoglu theorem**

Let X be a separable Banach space. If $\{f_n\}$ is a bounded sequence in X', then there exists a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ that converges weakly * to $f \in X'$.

**I have a couple of doubts regarding the hypothesis:

**1. Isn't requiring  $\{f_n\}$  to be bounded redundant?**

Since the $f_n$ are continuos (bounded) linear functionals, we have that by definition of bounded operator $\forall n$$\exists c_n$

$|f_n(x)|\le c_n \|x\|$  $\forall x\in X \implies \|f_n\| \le c_n $

Let $c = \max \{c_n, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$$\implies$ $\|f_n\| \le c < \infty$, Thus, the sequence $\{f_n\}$ is bounded . **What is wrong with this argument?**

**2 Is X' supposed to be the topological dual here or does it make sense to consider the algebraic dual only?** If X' were the algebraic dual, the sequence $\{f_n\}$ is made of linear functionals not necessarily continuous (bounded). In this case the boundedness hypothesis before would make sense for me, since my argument would no longer be possible

Comment: Why is $c < \infty$ if the sequence of functionals is not assumed to be bounded?

Comment: The max of a bunch of real numbers is a real number?

Comment: What if $\|f_n\| = n$?

Comment: An infinite set of real numbers might not have a max.  If you want to use a sup instead, then you need to know that the set of numbers is bounded above.  That's exactly what the boundedness hypothesis is doing for you here.

Comment: I see, thank you both, that clarifies question 1

Comment: $X'$ is the topological dual. for example, remember that the weak topology is the smallest topology that keeps the functionals of $X'$ continuous.

Comment: If we don't have the topology for the dual space $X'$, how do we talk about the convergence!